# Mocking constructor dependencies using AutoMoq attribute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I'm wondering if there is a way of setting up a mock for a dependency before the constructor of the System Under Test (SUT) is called when using a test case that sets up `AutoData`.

My SUT looks like:

```
class Sut
{
    private readonly IFoo foo;
    public Sut(IFooFactory factory)
    {
        this.foo = factory.Build(1, 2);
    }

    public IFoo Foo
    {
        get
        {
            return this.foo;
        }
    }
}
```

So the test that I'm writing looks like:

```
[Theory]
[AutoData]
internal void Foo_IsCorrectlySet_Test(
    [Frozen] Mock<IFooFactory> fooFactory,
    IFoo foo,
    Sut sut)
{
    fooFactory.Setup(mock => mock.Build(1, 2))
        .Returns(foo)
        .Verifiable();

    var actual = sut.Foo;

    Assert.Equal(foo, sut);
    fooFactory.Verify();
}
```

Obviously this test fails as the constructor to the `Sut` runs before I am able to setup the `IFooFactory`. So I thought that I may have been able to change the declaration of the `Sut` to `Lazy<Sut>` in the test.
But again the constructor is still run before the actual test code is run meaning that my test is going to fail.

Now I know that I could easily setup this test with an actual `Fixture` object and create all of my objects manually and setting them up before I call to create the `Sut` which is fine but I'm wanting to keep my tests all roughly the same therefore I'm wondering if there is a way that I could still setup my test with the `AutoData` attribute but not run the constructor until after everything is setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AutoFixture was originally build as a tool for Test-Driven Development (TDD), and TDD is all about **feedback**. In the spirit of [GOOS](http://amzn.to/VI81bP), you should **listen to your tests**. If the tests are hard to write, you should consider your API design. **AutoFixture tends to amplify that sort of feedback**, which may also be the case here.

Consider the invariants of the `Sut` class. Since it has a read-only `IFoo` class field, I'd interpret this as a strong indication that `IFoo` is a dependency of the class.

If that's the case, then inject `IFoo` via the constructor, instead of `IFooFactory`:

```
public class Sut
{
    private readonly IFoo foo;
    public Sut(IFoo foo)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public IFoo Foo
    {
        get { return this.foo; }
    }
}
```

You can still *compose* it using `IFooFactory` in the application's [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot):

```
var sut = new Sut(aFactory.Build(1, 2));
```

This will make the tests easier to write. I can't even show you how the above test would look with this refactoring, because it'd be redundant and can (and should) be deleted.

FWIW, the original design proposed above violates Nikola Malovic's 4th law of IoC that [constructors should do no work](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple).

Comment: +1 for quoting Nikola Malovic. Well, and for all your good points. Plus the pattern I quoted is yours so +3

Comment: This was what I was thinking of doing but obviously this pushes the use of the `IFooFactory` up to the `SutFactory` (there's a few different types of `ISut`) and I didn't think that it would be correct to be generating the dependencies of a class within it's own factory? And I cannot change the factory so that it happens before the call to the factory as some `ISut`s require the `IFooFactory` as a dependency as they use it to populate `Foo` after work is completed. Would the correct place therefore be in the `SutFactory`?

Comment: @StephenRoss I'm not sure I follow, but is this of any help? http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory Or this? http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling

Comment: Sort of (I have many `ISutFactories` which build different `ISut`s so sort of an Abstract Factory), but what I was getting at is is it OK to place any work in a factory? Obviously factories are a little more difficult to test which is why in this instance I believed the best port of call for this small functionality was in the constructor, although I fully understand the arguments against having any work in a constructor.

Comment: @StephenRoss What is the purpose of a class (any class)? Is the purpose of a class to have a constructor? Or is the purpose of the class to hold state and expose behaviour via its members? Put the work into the class according to the answers to these questions.

Comment: Thank you. I've just never came at a class from this direction before, but I see where I've been thinking incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Fixture object pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/03/16/FixtureObject/).
This allows you to setup your mocks before creating the `sut`.

Something in the lines of:

```
    private class Fixture
    {
        public Mock<FooFactory> FooFactoryMock { get; set; } = new Mock<FooFactory>();
        public Sut GetSut()
        {
            return new Sut(FooFactoryMock.Object);
        }
    }

    [Theory]
    [AutoData]
    internal void Foo_IsCorrectlySet_Test(
        IFoo foo)
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        fixture.FooFactory.Setup(mock => mock.Build(1, 2))
            .Returns(foo)
            .Verifiable();

        var sut = fixture.GetSut();
        var actual = sut.Foo;

        Assert.Equal(foo, sut);
        fooFactory.Verify();
    }
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying to avoid. I knew that this would be the 'easiest' method but I was trying to get away without having to create the `Fixture` in the test if possible. And also without having to call `new Sut(..)` at all.

Answer (score 0):

To set up your dependencies so that your sut class can obtain those mock dependencies, use customize classes that works well with AutoMoq setup.

```
public class CustomClassCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        var classAMock = fixture.Create<Mock<ClassA>>();
    var serviceProviderMock = new Mock<IServiceProvider>();
        serviceProviderMock.Setup(sp => sp.GetService(It.Is<Type>(t => t == typeof(ClassA)))).Returns(classAMock.Object);
    }
```